# Wanted: VSCode Extension to remember cursor positions in all files

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there already an vscode extension that

a) stores cursor position at file save time and
b) when re-opening a file restores the cursor position?

(PS: That's the last missing point to switch from notepad++ to vscode)

Comment: Not as session based but remembering cursor positions "for ever"

Answer (score 0):

It remembers the cursor position for me, both after closing the file and after closing VSCode.

On Windows it works exactly as expected. Under Ubuntu the window doesn't seem to show the cursor until I click the tab, but it's position is remembered.